# "Так называемая “теофания” - кавычки, прописная-строчная?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, кавычки

> Идеологический фон гостеприимства составляет так называемая теофания —
>   мифологическое представление о том, что Бог в человеческом облике
>   ходит по земле. Согласно адыгской пословице, имеющей многочисленные
>   параллели у других народов, «гость — посланник Бога».
>
> ---
>
> Рязанский филолог О. Е. Воронова указывает: «В своих первоистоках этот
>   мотив восходит к одной из древнейших общемировых культурных традиций —
>   так называемой “теофании”, мифологическому представлению о том, что
>   Бог в человеческом облике, в образе гостя ходит по земле.
>
> ---
>
> Это проявляется в так называемых теофаниях (букв. с греч.
>   «богоявление») – метафорах присутствия Бога среди людей, знаках,
>   которые Он дает человеку. Теофания – зримый знак того, что
>   принципиально незримо, незримой Божественной Сущности.

В моём тексте:

> Крупно выделена здесь фигура Царя Небесного. Нередко так изображался и
>   обожествлённый император. Подобные изображения, **так называемая
>   «Теофания»** — явление Христа во славе, не только указывали на земную
>   иерархию, но и воплощали идею апостольской преемственности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строчная буква, кавычек нет: **так называемая теофания**

1) Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169

Примечание. При словосочетании ***так называемый*** последующие слова в кавычки не заключаются. Исключение составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены в необычном или ироническом значении.

2) У подножия горы Синай Бог явился народу Израиля в физическом облике. Это называется **теофания** (также феофания, от греческого Θεοφανεια существительного Θεος «Бог» и глагола φαινω «я являю»). Вот несколько случаев явления Бога народу в Ветхом Завете  https://azbyka.ru/shemy/teofanii-v-vetkhom-zavete.shtml